# AJAX Open method and synchronicity

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm making a webpage that makes use of openweathermap.org API. for some reason, when I make an AJAX call and I open the API using weather.open(blah, blah, true)

```
function executeWeatherCity(cityName){
    var weather = new XMLHttpRequest();
    weather.open('GET', url + "q=" + cityName + apiKey, true);  //make a get request
    weather.send(null);
    var response = JSON.parse(weather.responseText); //store response properties
    document.getElementById('output').textContent = response.wind.speed; //store current wind speed
    event.preventDefault();
    weather.send(null);
}
```

the console is giving me an error on the line var response = JSON.parse(weather.responseText)

Originally, when I set the value to of weather.open  to(blah,blah, false) it worked (synchronous). I'm not sure if this is a gap in my understanding of synchronicity. But this is getting really frustrating because it should work based on comparable examples i've seen.

Also, whats interesting to note is that when I console.log(weather.status) I always get 0...Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are firing an asynchronous method, the response is not yet available after `.send()` method. You will have to use `onreadystatechange` event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

```
function executeWeatherCity(cityName){
    var weather = new XMLHttpRequest();
    weather.open('GET', url + "q=" + cityName + apiKey, true);  //make a get request
    weather.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if(weather.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && weather.status === 200)
          {
             var response = JSON.parse(weather.responseText); //store response properties
             document.getElementById('output').textContent = response.wind.speed; //store current temperatures           
          }
};
    weather.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a gap in your understanding :-)

Changing from synchronous to asynchronous makes it necessary for you to cope with the (asynchronous) response coming in "some time" after your code finished

That's why ajax gods invented an event called `readystatechange` which you can handle using `onreadystatechange` of the XMLLHttpRequest object

```
var weather = new XMLHttpRequest();
weather.open('GET', url + "q=" + cityName + apiKey, true);
weather.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(weather.readyState == 4 && weather.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(weather.responseText);
      document.getElementById('output').textContent = response.wind.speed;
   }
};
weather.send();
```

Comment: OK that makes sense, so basically theres a delay in the response that I have to account for before i try to access. Thanks!